# Can I automate container deployment into ACI form Azure container registry?

Tags: azure, azure-container-instances, azure-container-registry

Currently we have multiple ACI's deployed from images in ACR. But, as updated images are being pushed to ACR every day, is there any way to automate deployment of update image in ACI from ACR.

I didnt find much help related to webhooks in ACR. Please advise.

Comment: There'll be better answers than this but you could use the Events on the ACR to trigger something which updates the running container instance, could be a Pipeline in DevOps or can an Azure Function do the necessary work using the ACI SDK?!?  Something to think about.

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-using-azure-container-registry and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-ci-cd-custom-container?tabs=acr for guidance on this.

Comment: Thanks for comments. Checked with MS, comments are  "The container groups deployment automation can be done by: 
1. Create an Azure Logic App and a HTTP request trigger
2. Define container groups operations (Create, update, etc.)
3. Use the HTTP request trigger URL generated by Logic App for the ACR webhook Service URI
 
Auto-Deploy Container Images as Azure Container Instances (ACI) | marcelzehner.ch